# Android Studio IDE Errors since switching to AMD System

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been getting strange IDE errors in Android Studio since I swtiched to an AMD system,  Random Freezing also occurs (Not Sure if its related to the IDE Error?) which requires me to restart Android Studio.

I've tried both Windows 10 & Linux. Both are giving the same IDE Error + eventually freezing.

PC Specs

- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X CPU
- RX580 GPU
- Asus Rog Strix B450-F Mobo
- 16GB 3200mhz HyperX Predator Ram
- 650W EVGA PSU

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as the random Freezes are making working with android studio difficult.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's documentation. object #1 =com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashSet$MyRef@2174851b (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashSet$MyRef), hashCode=561284379; object #2 =com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashSet$MyRef@2174851b (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashSet$MyRef), hashCode=561284379
    at gnu.trove.TObjectHash.throwObjectContractViolation(TObjectHash.java:331)
    at gnu.trove.THashSet.rehash(THashSet.java:200)
    at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:286)
    at gnu.trove.THashSet.add(THashSet.java:146)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashSet.add(WeakHashSet.java:93)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.AbstractElementSignatureProvider.getChildIndex(AbstractElementSignatureProvider.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.JavaElementSignatureProvider.getSignature(JavaElementSignatureProvider.java:42)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingPolicy.getSignature(FoldingPolicy.java:33)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate$RegionInfo.createSignature(FoldingUpdate.java:321)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate$RegionInfo.<init>(FoldingUpdate.java:317)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate$RegionInfo.<init>(FoldingUpdate.java:303)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate.getFoldingsFor(FoldingUpdate.java:262)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate.getFoldingsFor(FoldingUpdate.java:226)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate.getUpdateResult(FoldingUpdate.java:98)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate.lambda$updateFoldRegions$0(FoldingUpdate.java:87)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.doCompute(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiParameterizedCachedValue.getValue(PsiParameterizedCachedValue.java:35)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getParameterizedCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.FoldingUpdate.updateFoldRegions(FoldingUpdate.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.CodeFoldingManagerImpl.updateFoldRegions(CodeFoldingManagerImpl.java:298)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.folding.impl.CodeFoldingManagerImpl.updateFoldRegionsAsync(CodeFoldingManagerImpl.java:284)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.CodeFoldingPass.doCollectInformation(CodeFoldingPass.java:42)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:423)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:416)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:415)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:391)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: are you using Trove TObjectHash? Switching CPU makes AndroidStudio problems sounds quite strange

Comment: Yes, it is strange :/ No i'm not using Trove TObjectHash, I've changed nothing in my project since using previous PC.

Comment: It's unlikely to be AMD related but more likely a general migration problem. It sounds like a cache inconsistency (the hash code computed on the old system is different from the hash code on the new system). Have you tried *File*/ *Invalidate Caches / Restart...*?

Comment: Yes Codo, I've tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart", I've Rebuilt project, cleaned project but issue still persists. Any other ideas?